# How to make a "play" button for Tumblrs Audio Player

Tags: tumblr

Is there ANYWAY to do this? What i'm trying to do is hide the default audio and instead add a button plays and pauses the audio. Maybe with [Tumblrs API?](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope unfortunately not, at least not as far as I know. As with Photosets, the player code gets automatically generated by the Tumblr templating system which gives you very little control other than to (1) use/not use it, and (2) change its colour (white, grey, and black).

Beyond that I don't think you can do much with it as even the API renders the embedded flash code (this is different for Photosets).

Hope it helps...